# Create column and populate it from the table name for many tables simultaneously_MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a couple of hundred absolutely identical MYSQL tables which contain 3 particularly important columns out of 10. The table names follow the pattern: name1_name2:

```
Table 1 name: r_t

chr, chromStart, chromEnd...

Table 2 name: y_g

chr, chromStart, chromEnd...
```

There's a MasterTable:

```
full_table_name, table_name_before_underscore, table_name_after_underscore
```

the 1st column consists of the full name of each table(**r_t** for the 1st table, **y_g** - for the 2nd), 2nd column - the first part of the table name before underscore(**r** and **y**), 3d - after underscore (**t** and **g**)

I need to get UNION_all_table with the chr, chrStart, chromEnd rows from every table and 2 additional columns consisting of the 1st part(before underscore) and 2nd part(after underscore) from every table name to distinguish from which table the data come from. For the 2 tables above:

```
Union_all_table:
chr, chrStart, chromEnd, table_name_before_underscore, table_name_after_underscore
1, 3456, 3487, r, t;
1, 3778, 3799, y, g;
```

Prepared statement doesnt work for Alter table, Update table, so I can't see the way to do it  by means of MYSQL only.

Many thanks for any ideas!

Comment: *Why* do you have "a couple of hundred absolutely identical MYSQL tables"???  This is a very denormalised schema, which is (generally speaking) incredibly poor design.  Better to amalgamate into a single table with an extra column that identifies their differences.

Comment: Eggyal, I've downloaded the date from the internet in such presentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by “Prepared statement doesnt work for Alter table, Update table”? The following [works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c054/1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a, b CHAR(1);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT table_name_before_underscore,
           table_name_after_underscore
    FROM master;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  OPEN CUR;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO a, b;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET @query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO Union_all_table SELECT ',
                        'chr, chromStart, chromEnd, \'',
                        a, '\', \'', b, '\' FROM ',
                        a, '_', b);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;
END //

CALL proc() //
```

Note that this does create a table, not a union view, so it won't reflect any modifications in your input tables. I suggest you execute this query once, then scrap your original tables and replace them with views of this new union table.